# How do I get the sizeOf() an array across payloads

Tags: dataweave

I have multiple payloads of Account records. I want to get the size across all payloads. Can't figure it out.

[image: av]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this input

```
{
 "0": {
  "inboundAttachmentNames": [

  ],
  "exceptionPayload": null,
  "inboundPropertyNames": [

  ],
  "outboundAttachmentNames": [

  ],
  "payload": {
   "meta": {
    "totalItems": 3,
    "pagingOffset": 1,
    "pagingLimit": 10,
    "orderBy": "",
    "orderAscDesc": ""
   },
   "account.Account": [
    {
     "sourceSystem": "Salesforce",
     "name": "Coca-Cola",
     "accountId": "Salesforce-1",
     "customerId": "Salesforce-c1"
    },
    {
     "sourceSystem": "Salesforce",
     "name": "Levi Strauss",
     "accountId": "Salesforce-2",
     "customerId": "Salesforce-c2"
    },
    {
     "sourceSystem": "Salesforce",
     "name": "Remmington Arms",
     "accountId": "Salesforce-3",
     "customerId": "Salesforce-c3"
    }
   ]
  },
  "outboundPropertyNames": [

  ],
  "attributes": {
   "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "content-length": "605",
    "date": "Fri, 24 Jan 2020 14:33:03 GMT"
   },
   "reasonPhrase": "OK",
   "statusCode": 200
  }
 },
 "1": {
  "inboundAttachmentNames": [

  ],
  "exceptionPayload": null,
  "inboundPropertyNames": [

  ],
  "outboundAttachmentNames": [

  ],
  "payload": {
   "meta": {
    "totalItems": 2,
    "pagingOffset": 1,
    "pagingLimit": 10,
    "orderBy": "",
    "orderAscDesc": ""
   },
   "account.Account": [
    {
     "sourceSystem": "SAP",
     "name": "addidas",
     "accountId": "sap-1",
     "customerId": "sap-c1"
    },
    {
     "sourceSystem": "SAP",
     "name": "BMW",
     "accountId": "sap-2",
     "customerId": "sap-c2"
    }
   ]
  },
  "outboundPropertyNames": [

  ],
  "attributes": {
   "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "content-length": "399",
    "date": "Fri, 24 Jan 2020 14:33:03 GMT"
   },
   "reasonPhrase": "OK",
   "statusCode": 200
  }
 }
```

}

The script is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import valueSet from dw::core::Objects
---
sum(valueSet(payload) map ((item) -> sizeOf(item.payload."account.Account")))
```